Switch user before running cmd ubuntu
I'm trying to run a cron job in ubuntu server to backup my database every day.
so Im using this cmd:
sudo -i -u postgres && pg_dump -Fc DbName > DbName_backup.dump && ... && ... && ...

the problem I have is that you can not switch user and run command in a single statement, it never works.
I have to call sudo -i -u postgres then in another statement call pg_dump -Fc DbName > DbName_backup.dump && ... && ... && ...
But I want it to work in a single statement. in a single line!!!

See https://serverfault.com/questions/241262/how-to-run-a-crontab-as-another-user

@clamp thanks for reply, cron job that I'm using is a GUI software that I use.
let's forget about cron, is there a way to run this command right inside terminal and just work?

sudo doesn't "switch users"; it runs a single command as another user. You can have that single command be a separate shell instance that parses and executes the rest of your list.
sudo -i -u postgres sh -c 'pgdump -Fc DbName > DbName_backup.dump && ... && ... && ...'

This adds a level of quoting, which might make providing the argument for sh -c more difficult. As such you might consider just putting your commands in a file to execute as single script.
